# Good regex to extract price

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract price from various currency values. Here are my sample input values:

```
でレンタル HD(高画質) ￥ 500
で購入　　HD(高画質) ￥ 2,500
Buy SD £5.99
Buy SD £14.99
HD ausleihen EUR 3,99
HD kaufen EUR 11,99
Buy Movie HD $19.99
$1,200.84
```

How would I get this currency value into a float, for example `19.99` ? The regex I had so far is:

```
re.findall(r'[\d|\,|\.]+', s)[0].replace(',', '')
```

But it seems insufficient. What would be a better one?

Comment: Can you also show us how this current regex performs on your sample data?

Comment: This seems like a mismatch of technologies. You don't really want *one* regex for 1000 situations; chances are a hierarchy of them will deal with outliers better. An NLP program might do even better. You also don't really want to store currency in a float; an integer works much better for that.

Comment: `re.findall("[\d.,]+",s)` would also work

Comment: Do the prices always appear last on the line?

Comment: I don't know python but you could start with something like: `(?:￥|£|EUR|\$)\s*([\d,]+(?:\.\d{2})?)` maybe; https://regex101.com/r/xI9sG1/1 This also assumes you don't care about the currency unit, if you do take off the non-capturing grouping of the first group.

Comment: @chris85 thanks for that -- that works pretty well with that pattern.

Comment: If that resolves the issue let me know and I'll post that as an answer. I don't have anywhere to test python though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex that will match ANY currencies from a string, before or after a currency type word/symbol, you may use

```
(?:\b(?:USD|GBP|EUR|JPY|CHF|SEK|DKK|NOK|SGD|HKD|AUD|TWD|NZD|CNY|KRW|INR|CAD|VEF|EGP|THB|IDR|PKR|MYR|PHP|MXN|VND|CZK|HUF|PLN|TRY|ZAR|ILS|ARS|CLP|BRL|RUB|QAR|AED|COP|PEN|CNH|KWD|SAR)|[$\u00A2-\u00A5\u058F\u060B\u07FE\u07FF\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20C0\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6\U00011FDD-\U00011FE0\U0001E2FF\U0001ECB0])\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)|(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)\s*(?:(?:USD|GBP|EUR|JPY|CHF|SEK|DKK|NOK|SGD|HKD|AUD|TWD|NZD|CNY|KRW|INR|CAD|VEF|EGP|THB|IDR|PKR|MYR|PHP|MXN|VND|CZK|HUF|PLN|TRY|ZAR|ILS|ARS|CLP|BRL|RUB|QAR|AED|COP|PEN|CNH|KWD|SAR)\b|[$\u00A2-\u00A5\u058F\u060B\u07FE\u07FF\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20C0\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6\U00011FDD-\U00011FE0\U0001E2FF\U0001ECB0])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ES36bX/1). It includes `USD|GBP|EUR|JPY|CHF|SEK|DKK|NOK|SGD|HKD|AUD|TWD|NZD|CNY|KRW|INR|CAD|VEF|EGP|THB|IDR|PKR|MYR|PHP|MXN|VND|CZK|HUF|PLN|TRY|ZAR|ILS|ARS|CLP|BRL|RUB|QAR|AED|COP|PEN|CNH|KWD|SAR` pattern that matches most common world currencies and `[$\u00A2-\u00A5\u058F\u060B\u07FE\u07FF\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20C0\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6\U00011FDD-\U00011FE0\U0001E2FF\U0001ECB0]` that matches any currency symbols (equivalent of `\p{Sc}` in PCRE).

In Python, you will need a bit of code to make it work as you need:

```py
import re
texts = ['でレンタル HD(高画質) ￥ 500',
    'で購入　　HD(高画質) ￥ 2,500',
    'Buy SD £5.99',
    'Buy SD £14.99',
    'HD ausleihen EUR 3,99',
    'HD kaufen EUR 11,99',
    'Buy Movie HD $19.99',
    '$1,200.84'
]
curword = r'(?:USD|GBP|EUR|JPY|CHF|SEK|DKK|NOK|SGD|HKD|AUD|TWD|NZD|CNY|KRW|INR|CAD|VEF|EGP|THB|IDR|PKR|MYR|PHP|MXN|VND|CZK|HUF|PLN|TRY|ZAR|ILS|ARS|CLP|BRL|RUB|QAR|AED|COP|PEN|CNH|KWD|SAR)'
cursymbol = r'[$\u00A2-\u00A5\u058F\u060B\u07FE\u07FF\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20C0\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6\U00011FDD-\U00011FE0\U0001E2FF\U0001ECB0]'
num = r'\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*'
pattern = re.compile(fr'(?:\b{curword}|{cursymbol})\s*({num})|({num})\s*(?:{curword}\b|{cursymbol})')
print(fr'(?:\b{curword}|{cursymbol})\s*({num})|({num})\s*(?:{curword}\b|{cursymbol})')

for text in texts:
    m = pattern.search(text)
    if m:
        result = m.group(1) or m.group(2)
        print(result)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sCcA82). It prints

```
500
2,500
5.99
14.99
3,99
11,99
19.99
1,200.84
```

If you need to convert string result to int/float, you can also capture the country currency word/symbol, then convert the decimal separator to the one you need and then parse to `int` or `float`.